# In-memory database vs RAM-disk

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database

In SQLite, are there any differences in performance/features/reliability/... between:

1) an in-memory database:  `rc = sqlite3_open("file::memory:", &db);`

2) a database on a RAM-disk?

The database must be accessible from multiple processes.